# Firebase analytics working only for Android (React Native Expo App)

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

So I built a React Native App with expo. I wanted to add Firebase Analytics so I followed expo's instructions:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/

My app is already published in Google Play Store and Apple Store, and my Firebase Dashboard only show's Android's analytics. It's as if IOS was never activated, yet I followed the instructions rigorously. My app.json looks like this picture (1):
[app.json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxTrO.png)

I have both services files in the correct folder, so i don't know what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could solve this. Apparently Firebase in IOS through Expo, takes a little bit more time to activate. After 2 weeks runing in Android, Firebase Analytics started to run on IOS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).